# Dockerfile change file permission during COPY

Tags: docker

I'd like to change permissions on certificates that I'm coping into image filesystem. What's the easiest way?

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

COPY assets/ /usr/share/ca-certificates/orsted/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `--chmod=644` flag to `COPY` or `ADD` instruction as on the example below.

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

COPY --chmod=644 assets/certs /usr/share/ca-certificates/acme/
```

If you need to change owner of the files as well, then add `--chown=nobody:nogroup` flag.

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

COPY --chmod=644 --chown=nobody:nogroup assets/certs /usr/share/ca-certificates/acme/
```

**Important**:
the `--chmod` option requires BuildKit. Refer to https://docs.docker.com/go/buildkit/ to learn how to build images with BuildKit enabled